# Using GAP to determine when cosets are equal to each other.

Tags: group-theory, gap

Let $P1 = SL_{2} (\mathbb{F}_{2} [[t]])$ and $P2= \{ [a \; t^{-1}b ; tc \; d] | a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{F}_{2}[[t]], ad-bc = 1 \}$. I am considering cosets of $P1$ and $P2$. For instance, $[0 -1/t; t 0]P1$ and $[0 \; -1 ; 1\; 0 ]P2$.

I want to multiply these cosets on the left by elements of a group with generating set $\{ [1 \; 1 ; 0 \; 1], [1 \; t ; 0 \; 1] , [1 \; 0 ; 1 \; 1] [1 \; 0 ; t \; 1] , [t \; 0 ; 0 \; t^{-1}] \}$.

How can I use GAP to determine when these cosets are equal to each other?

Comment: Your last matrix is not invertible...

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected it.

Comment: Something is still wrong. The group P1 is infinite, the group P2 finite, so their cosets can never be equal. Also, cosets in which overgroup? And it seems that P2 and also the third, unnamed group (the one acting from the left) are contained in P1. So perhaps something got mixed up?